# Docker notification on new image version

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to build a docker image which is based on the official node docker image and was wondering if there is some way of automatically rebuilding the image when a new version of the official node image gets pushed. So that my image isn't based on an outdated base image.

Maybe there is some way like rss-feed, where updates to the official images get published, so that I could listen to that feed?

Or is there some other way to get notified by new images on the official docker-registry?

Answer (score 4):

By default, updates of base `Docker images` must be manually pulled and applied to each running container.

Hence, you are probably looking for a third-party tool like [Watchtower](https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower), which automates the process of detecting updates for your `Docker container`’s base image.

Specifically, the aforementioned tool watches a specified `Docker image repository` for new `Docker image` pushes. This repository can be either private or public, and hosted on the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) registry or on your own image registry.

In your case, you can create a `docker-compose` file, as shown below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  node:
    image: node:fermium-alpine3.16
    container_name: fahrecker-node-container
  watchtower:
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    container_name: watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: fahrecker-node-container
```

Finally, you may also enable email notification functionality, by adding a few environmental variables, as shown below:

```
environment:
  WATCHTOWER_MONITOR_ONLY: 'true'
  WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATIONS: email
  WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_FROM: <EMAIL_FROM>
  WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_TO: <EMAIL_TO>
  WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_SERVER: smtp.provider.com
  WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_SERVER_PORT: 587 (in most cases)
  WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_SERVER_USER: <YOUR_EMAIL>
  WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD: <YOUR_PASSWORD>
```